# How to check column count in a file to satisfy a condition

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to check the column count and see if it satisfies the condition or else throw error or email.
something I have tried:

```
$columns=(Get-Content "C:\Users\xs15169\Desktop\temp\OEC2_CFLOW.txt" | select  -First 1).Split(",")
$Count=columns.count
if ($count -eq 280)
  echo "column count is:$count"
else 
  email
```

Comment: Can we assume that the input file is a CSV?

Comment: No, I was trying to perform  this on .txt file

Comment: Lookup the correct syntax of the if command `Get-Help about_if`

Comment: @harishv But is the txt file in CSV format (it is considered CSV even if another delimeter is used)? Hard to imagine you are working with a column-based text file that isn't CSV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume your text file is in CSV format, I can't imagine what format you're working with if it's a text-file table and not formatted as CSV.

## If your CSV has headers

Process the CSV file, and count the number of properties on the resulting Powershell object.

```
$columnCount = @( ( Import-Csv '\path\to\file.txt' ).PSObject.Properties ).Count
```

We need to force the `Properties` object to an array (which is the `@()` syntax) to accurately get the count. The `PSObject` property is a hidden property for metadata about an object in Powershell, which is where we look for the `Properties` (column names) and get the count of how many there are.

## CSV without headers

If your CSV doesn't have headers, `Import-Csv` requires you to manually specify the headers. There are tricks you can do to build out unique column names on-the-fly, but they are overly complex for simply getting a column count.

To take what you've already tried above, we can get the data in the first line and process the number of columns, though you were doing it incorrectly in the question. Here's how to properly do it:

```
$columnCount = ( ( Get-Content "\path\to\file.txt" | Select-Object -First 1 ) -Split ',' ).Count
```

## What was wrong with the original

Both above solutions consolidate getting the column count down to one line of code. But in your original sample, you made a couple small mistakes:

```
$columns=( Get-Content "\path\to\file.txt" | select  -First 1 ).Split(",")

# You forgot to prepend "columns" with a $. Should look like the below line
$Count=$columns.count
```

And you forgot to use curly braces with your `if` block:

```
if ($count -eq 280) {
  echo "column count is:$count"
} else { 
  email
}
```

As for using the `-Split` operator vs. the `.Split()` method - this is purely stylistic preference on my part, and using `Split()` is perfectly valid.

Comment: getting this error : Import-Csv : The member "00000000000000.00" is already present.

Comment: Do you have multiple columns with the same name?

Comment: few of the columns contain same data, I have to take the count of columns and see if it matches the expected number

Comment: The CSV doesn't have any headers? I'll post an alternative solution. You have to manually specify header names in this case, and while I can think of a few ways to process it dynamically, they won't be simple.

Comment: Whatever the file I'm dealing doesn't have the header names, All I have to check is it contains the 280 columns or not.

Comment: Added another solution above without using `Import-Csv`, builds off of your original attempt. And if it's something you can control/suggest, I would strongly recommend generating a header line in your CSVs, though it isn't required.

Comment: Thanks for the above  answer it was working fine, Now i have situation where need to introduce this column count condition for each and every file which i unzip......My process is as follows below: